# What is the difference between Nhibernate and SubSonic?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, subsonic

I know that NHibernate is a very powerful ORM but SubSonic is not known for me.
please give me a little information about SubSonic and tell me that What is the difference between Nhibernate and SubSonic ?

Comment: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/subsonic-vs-nhibernate">here</a> is a similar question that was asked a while ago which might help.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/subsonic-vs-nhibernate